# Need help for a circuit diagram using Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am a beginner with drawing circuits in Latex. And there is one circuit where I am stuck and it would be great if someone could help. The circuit is as shown below:

[image]

The upper half is the difficult part for me.

The code for what I have done till now :

```
 \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}

    \ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0)
    node[nmos, xscale=-1, anchor = D](nmos4){}
    (nmos4.G) node[nmos, anchor = G](nmos5){}
    (nmos4.S) node[nmos, anchor = D](nmos1){}
    (nmos5.S) node[nmos, xscale=-1,anchor = D](nmos2){}
    (nmos4.D) -- (nmos5.D) 
    (nmos1.S) -- (nmos2.S)
    (nmos1.S) node[nmos, xshift = 1cm, anchor = D](nmos3){}
    (nmos3.S) node[ground]{V\textsc{ss}}
    (nmos3.G) node[anchor=east]{Vb}
    (nmos2.G) node[anchor=west]{Vin2}
    (nmos1.G) node[anchor=east]{Vin1}
    (nmos4.D) node[anchor=south,xshift=1cm]{V\textsc{dd}};
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could show us the part that you got until now. So we don't need to start from scratch, especially as the lower part is not difficult, as you said.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Sorry I am new to Tex.stackexchange as well. Next time will keep in mind to show what I have tried first and then ask questions. Now I have edited the question which includes the code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.8cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0)
    node[pmos, xscale=-1, anchor = S](pmos4){}
    (pmos4.G) node[pmos, anchor = G, xshift=1.2cm](pmos5){}
    (pmos4.D) to[short] ++(0,-1) node[nmos, anchor = D](nmos1){}
    (pmos5.D) to[short] ++(0,-1) node[nmos, xscale=-1,anchor = D](nmos2){}
    (pmos4.S) to[short] (pmos5.S)
    (nmos1.S) to[short] (nmos2.S)
    (pmos4.D) to[short,*-] ++(1,0) to[short] (pmos5.G)
    (pmos5.D) to[short,*-] ++(-1,0) to[short] (pmos4.G)
    (nmos1.D) to[short,*-o] ++(1,0)
    (nmos2.D) to[short,*-o] ++(-1,0)
    ($(nmos1.D)!0.5!(nmos2.D)$) node {$V_{\mathrm{out}}$}
    ($(nmos1.S)!0.5!(nmos2.S)$) to[short,*-] ++(0,0) node[nmos, anchor = D](nmos3){}
    (nmos3.S) node[ground] {}
    (nmos3.G) to[short,-*] ++(0,0) node[anchor=east]{$V_{\mathrm{b}}$}
    (nmos2.G) to[short,*-o] ++(0,0) node[anchor=west]{$V_{\mathrm{in2}}$}
    (nmos1.G) to[short,*-o] ++(0,0) node[anchor=east]{$V_{\mathrm{in1}}$}
    ($(pmos4.S)!0.5!(pmos5.S)$)  node[anchor=south]{$V_{\mathrm{DD}}$}
    (pmos4) node[left] {$M_3$}
    (pmos5) node[right] {$M_4$}
    (nmos1) node[right] {$M_1$}
    (nmos2) node[left] {$M_2$}
    (nmos3) node[right] {$M_5$};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments:

- I added an horizontal shift between M3 and M4 to avoid the gates to overlap
- I empoyed the `short` style of circuitikz to be able to add connections (with `*` or `o`, resp. closed or poen symbols)
- The notation `($ coordinate !0.5! other coordinate$)` can be used to compute the midpoint
- I used math mode for subscript in nodes.

Then, from a circuit point of view, M3 and M4 are p type MOS in the original diagram, so I changed the node type.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for the help. I will go through the code in detail to understand it fully!!